# Tab completion does not work in python org src

Tags: python, emacs, org-babel, emacs-lsp

I set up a python org src

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
import sys

print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
: [GCC 7.3.0]
: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

After strike `C-'` to invoke a code buffer, the tab completion refused to work as intented.

Even though activated the python-mode and lsp-mode

[image]

ob-ipython did not work as well.

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes :results output
(print (emacs-version))
(print (org-version))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 
: "GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.11)
:  of 2019-09-23, modified by Debian"
: 
: "9.3"
```

Comment: this must be an issue specific to `lsp-mode` (probably requiring a file associated with the buffer), as `company-anaconda` works fine in this case

Comment: ty. @picklerick tI use doom-emacs he problem troubled me long ago when I employed company-anaconda, so switched to lsp-mode. My colleagues do not encounter such problems.